# Parse XML with multiple namespace to JSON - PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I want to access the XML and parse it as JSON.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:ser='http://service.billing.org/'>
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body>
  <ser:processTrans>
     <xmlValue>
         <![CDATA[
            <ebpacket> 
                <head> 
                    <packettype> UserAuthorization</packettype>
                    <staffcode> ePay_UserName  </staffcode> 
                    <pwd>  ePay_Password </pwd>
                </head> 
                <body>
                    <email> _username  </email>
                    <loginpwd>  _password  </loginpwd>
                    <deviceid>  DeviceId  </deviceid>
                </body>
            </ebpacket>
        ]]>
    </xmlValue>
  </ser:processTrans>
```

I am able to access the values the following way:

```
$xml_str = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $xmlstr);
$xml = SimpleXML_Load_String($xml_str,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ser', 'http://service.billing.org');
$j_obj = json_encode($xml->xpath('//soapenv:Body'));
```

The problem is that, XML structure is not known in advance. Hence, I cannot specifically access through the namespace. Unless I specify the namespace **$xml->xpath('//soapenv:Body')**, it does not return the expected result.

Comment: have you tried using dom ? you can get the namespace from domdocument  and do the same

Comment: You're going to need to traverse the document, looking at the namespaces available at each level (because prefixes can be redefined on any node), and deciding how to represent them in your JSON (including the namespace URI would be most correct, as prefixes can change arbitrarily). You might get some clues from the implementation of https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your getting the two namespaces mixed up, your trying to register the `soapenv` prefix with the URI used for `ser`.  Not that this affects the code, but it may not give what your expecting.

As for not knowing the namespaces in advance, in SimpleXML you can use `getDocNamespaces()` to fetch the namespaces from the document and then loop through and register them against the prefixes.  So the following code fetches the XML content of the Body...

```
$xml_str = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $xmlstr);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_str,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$ns = $xml->getDocNamespaces(true);
foreach ( $ns as $prefix => $URI )   {
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace($prefix, $URI);
}
$j_obj = json_encode($xml->xpath('//soapenv:Body/*'));
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake I made in the question. I have edited it. It doesn't work that way too

Comment: I want to access without mentioning the ** '//ser:processTrans' **in the code as the structure of the XML is dynamic.

Comment: I've updated the xpath expression, can you try that.

Comment: The above works. But, is there a way to access the elements just by the "prefix"? for instance, just by using "soapenv" instead of "soapenv:Body"

Comment: Depends - you could do something like `$xml->xpath('//soapenv:*');`, which searches for all elements with that prefix - in the sample XML it will find 3 - soapenv:Envelope, soapenv:Header and soapenv:Body.