# Working with CDATA / Soap / PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

So, I have this xml file:

[xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z580A.png)

I use this code to get this xml on php with soap

```
$response = $clientrepasse->__soapCall("GetSchema", array($paramsrepasse));
$return = $clientrepasse->__getLastResponse()
```

When I show this `$return` with my `print_r` function I got this

[return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBX4d.png)

When I use function var_dump it shows that the $return is a string(40000) positions.

I tried:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($return);
```

When I print `$xml` it's empty, I need to transform that string to xml and then to `json`, or something like that, because I need to work on that xml.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you and sorry about my english.

Comment: You need to express code using the code formatting markup and not the quotation formatting markup or pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML has namespaces. simplexml does not load XMLs into an XML object when it has namespaces. You have to register your namespace to be able to load the XML using simplexml_load_string.

Check the link below:
[XML to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280427/php-xml-to-json-fails)
 [XML to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299894/parse-xml-with-multiple-namespace-to-json-php)

Post XML to get the answer specific to your XML .

Comment: I have posted my xml, both images are from my xml

Comment: Post your XML as "code sample" on your question. Not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to call `__getLastResponse()`. It gives you the raw HTTP body as a string, which isn't what you want.

This should be all you need:

```
$response = $clientrepasse->GetSchema($paramsrepasse);
print_r($response);
```

You don't need to work with XML. `$response` will be a PHP object that you can work with straight away.

Note that you also don't need to call `__soapCall()` directly either.